# Foundation Sass Install App.css error

Tags: sass, gruntjs, zurb-foundation, bower

Followed the instructions to download the sass Foundation version. (http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html)

I keep getting the following error in app.css

```
Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: foundation/_functions.
Load path: /Users/xxx/Desktop/sandbox/app
on line 13 of scss/_settings.scss
from line 1 of ./scss/app.scss
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of the foundation folder there should be a file named _functions.  The underscore in front of the name indicates that it's a partial file and is compiled into app.css using @import.

1: Check to see if _functions is in the foundation folder

2: If it is, check your import path

3: If it's not, try downloading Foundation again

Just as a tip, I like to use a app called [Mixture.io](http://mixture.io).  In addition to having a lots of its own features, it makes setting up a Foundation project a cinch.

Hope this helps.